# Any tool to convert bulk php files to UTF-8 without BOM?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I have a very large script which contains a lot of php files, so I need some Windows tool to convert all those files into UTF-8 without BOM.  (I know this can be done with Notepad++ but would require doing each file separately.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a tool such as iconv from [GnuWin32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuWin32) and run a batch script to process all of your files that way.

But what encoding are they now? If they're ANSI, and you're not using any bytes with values => 128, then they're already BOM-less UTF-8. Perhaps you can use that to narrow down the number of files you'd have to process - maybe enough that you only have a few files to convert (and might prefer to do it on an individual basis).

Answer (score 8):

I have used with success **UTFCast** on Windows.

It has a GUI, and is very easy to use, so you don't have to fiddle with command line scripts.

There's an "[Express](http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-express.aspx)" free version that can do what you want, and a [Pro version](http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-professional.aspx) with more options (has a 14 day trial).

You can see [here a comparison chart of both versions](http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-version-comparison.aspx), to see if it suits your needs.

Express detects less codepages, but for me its worst defect is that has no filter, for only process PHP files and not JS for example.

[image: UTFCast Express]

The Pro version beyond the 14 days can be used to browse folders and detect encoding of files, but not to convert.

[image: UTFCast Pro]

Comment: Do not download this software guys, it is locked and doesnt do anything else than installing browser addons !

Comment: It worked all right for me, @thecore7. Where did you downloaded this from? Was it from the official webpage, or a general download site?

Comment: Helped me; did what I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I do it with Notepad++.

Before trying this, you **must** make a backup of your files.

You need to create a macro that does this:

1. Convert the currently opened file to UTF-8 w/o BOM;
2. Select all the text in your file, and copy it (why this? it looks like a bug. if you won't do this, your file will be replaced with your current clipboard content...);
3. Save the current file;
4. Close the current file.

Save this macro.

Now, open your PHP files, and run it with the "Run a Macro Multiple Times..." command.
If you opened 100 files, let it run for 100 times.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but Notepad++ is completely buggy when doing this. I ended up with UTF-8 files which had invalid code points in them because the ANSI characters were copied to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of [this page](http://schneegans.de/frontpage/utf-8/) you’ll find a VBscript which converts any number of files per drag and drop.